# Как поочередно использовать перенаправление в одной команде?

Tags: javascript, консоль

Как поочередно использовать перенаправление в консоли браузера с помощью одной команды?

Код ниже перенаправляет только на последнюю ссылку

```
function sleep(millis) {
    var t = (new Date()).getTime();
    var i = 0;
    while (((new Date()).getTime() - t) < millis) {
        i++;
    }
}

var a = [" https://a1.com", " https://a2.com", " https://a3.com"]
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(a[i]);
    sleep(1000)
    location.href = a[i];
}
```

Comment: Что за перенаправление в консоли? Как вы поочередно будете перенаправлять, если первое же перенаправление остановит выполнение вашего скрипта и будет загружена другая страница?

Answer (score -1):

Можешь глянуть [эту ссылку](https://learn.javascript.ru/window-methods#dostup-k-novomu-oknu), но я рекомендую сменить тз, и\или подучить js (от *var* и *func* отказаться)

Фу какой sleep, лучше его **убрать** как можно скорее, вот держи нормальный (асинхронный):

```js
const sleep=(ms)=>new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(r, ms));
```

Comment: как можно отказаться от _func_?

Comment: @Grundy [очень просто](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Так это те же самые функции, плюс они не всегда могут заменить `function`